# Generating Geoserver Map Tiles

Tags: geoserver

I created an Azure VM with 640GB Ram and 80 vCPUs in an attempt to generate map tiles faster. However, regardless of the computing power Geoserver doesn't seem to be utilising all the resources available. I have already tried increasing the DB connections, max Java memory available, etc but have had no success. I will be very grateful if someone could advise.

Comment: please give us details of how you are generating map tiles, how many instances of GeoServer are you running? how are the caches synchronised? how complex are the styles? what database are you running and where? What exact settings have you used? what speeds are you seeing?

Comment: I have a single instance of Geoserver accessing a PaaS instance of SQL server. Datastore has min/max connections set to 200, fetch size 1000 and big connection timeout. DB only has a DTU utilisation of 20%. Tile image format required is png8. I was seeding with 16 tasks and only saw about 20% CPU utilisation at max for 80 cores being available. I have optimised JVM settings as on Geoserver website and am also using Marlin as the rendering engine. I want to be able to use up all resources available so that I can generate the Tiles as quickly as possible.Tiles are stored on nVME drive.

Comment: 16 tasks won't use more than 16 cores so try increasing that. Please use the [edit] button to update your question

Comment: I had configured an xml file in a gwc jar that limited the number tasks. However, there was a comment in this configuration that the number of tasks can't be increased more than 32. I made a rest api call to execute 32 tasks but still couldn't go any faster. I found that the performance was the same in terms of the number of tiles being generated but now split across 32 tasks. I had also tried attaching multiple NVME drives and striping them to get more IOPS but was unable to identify the bottleneck preventing the use of all resources available.